# In java why do primitive not need the .equals method?

Tags: java

So in java if your comparing strings you have to use the .equals method, because == only compares the memory address not the contents. That’s fine I can wrap my head around that. But what I don’t understand is why don’t primitive have the same problem. How are we able to use the == operator for primitives.

Comment: Because primitives are not objects and don't have references. There is therefore no duality existing in the operator

Comment: It's easier to understand if you imagine how it's implemented under the hood. A String reference is (kinda-sorta) a number like 9876 that should be interpreted as a memory location where you can find character data. A primitive integer is a number like 5432 that should just be interpreted as itself. In both cases, `==` compares that number itself, with no consideration to what it may or may not point to.

Comment: It is kind of funny that you use the word "primitive" to differentiate it from an "object", but then still choose to be confused by it as if they would be the same thing. No. Two different things. With two different names. And two different semantics. It's as simple as that. In the future you'll be your own worst enemy with a different question: is Java truly an object oriented language because it supports primitives? I warn you now - wars have been waged over it. In Call of Duty, but still.

Comment: primitives are primitives, that is, not an object and so they have no methods at all